# recursive method to display a string backwards but while loop doesn't work

Tags: string, if-statement, recursion, while-loop

I tried to write a recursive method that displays the contents of a string backwards. And I don't understand why the while loop in the method doesn't work as I expected, it keeps looping and looping. 
However, if I use **if/else** loop, it seems to work perfectly. 
But I just want to understand what happens to the while loop.

```
 public class printString{

    void BitString(String a, int i){
        while (i > 0){
            System.out.println(i);
            //System.out.println(a.substring(i-1, i));
            i--;
            BitString(a.substring(0, i), i);
        }
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        printString print = new printString();

        String str = "I am a beginner.";
        int i = str.length() -1;

        print.BitString(str, i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit modify the code.

Here 4 things missing

1)getting substring
What substring method says:The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1 
Here every time last char is lost,Because of that index out of range exception is occuring

2)The count(length) should be decreased after substring method,while passing parameter

3)return statement is missing..!!,there must be return statement else program runs infinite times.

4)while condition  while (i >= 0)

```
void BitString(String a, int i){

    while (i >= 0){
        System.out.print(a.charAt(i));
        //i--;
        BitString(a.substring(0, i), --i);
        return;//Missing return

    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you for tour explanation. I just have 1 more question.3)return statement is missing..!!,there must be return statement else program runs infinite times.

Comment: In my origin code, I thought when I set while ( i  > 0), and i decreases to 0, then it will not enter to while loop, and then program will run the return statement outside of while loop, thus will not loop endlessly. But that didn't happen..... I am just a bit confused about it.